# Why I need to reset frequently SMC controller in my MacBook Pro with touch bar (Intel, T1 Chip)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, power-management, restart

I have a MacBook Pro with Touch Bar and an Intel processor. I need to reset the SMC controller every time I open the MacBook Pro. It does not start automatically unless I do this.

I've tried many solutions, but it doesn’t work. I've also updated to macOS Big Sur.

When I shut it down, the screen shows a green screen or RGB color pixels and lines.

Model: MacBook Pro 2016 Model

macOS: Big Sur(11.1)

This issue also present in my previous version macOS Catalina.

[image]

Comment: Welcome on Ask Different. Please have a Look at the tour: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour. We need more details, e.g what exact MacBook, which macOS version and maybe also a picture of the described RGB color pixel lines :) I think that you can disable auto start in the terminal. May that be the problem here?

Comment: No its does not like that, i also try with press power button but its still not start. i always need to reset SMC.

Comment: Have you done a clean install of macOS?

Comment: Yes, i update my macOS once. after i also re-install macOS.

Comment: Reinstalling is different from a clean install. Clean install means erasing the drive and then starting from scratch. Have you tried that?

Comment: No, i don't try clean install of macOS. How can i do that? Do you have any references?

Comment: https://www.idownloadblog.com/2020/11/24/clean-install-macos-big-sur-tutorial/ You can follow that guide. General procedure is: **back-up your system**, create a USB installer, wipe the drive, install macOS from the usb, restore files/apps.

Comment: i try clean install macOS. but its does not work.